# MarkupCore - Is it possible to disable rightClick on a hovered markup in ForgeViewer?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

Whenever I hover a markup and right click it, it locks the mouse movement to the drawing and makes it impossible to move the mouse without moving the drawing.

Is it possible to disable this behaviour?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on your specific scenario, there's a few things you can try:

If you're trying to enable camera pan while in the markup mode on a 2D drawing, you can simply "enable navigation" for the markup tool:

```js
viewer.toolController.getTool('markups.core').allowNavigation(true);
```

If that's not sufficient for your case, you could also try and modify the `handleButtonDown` method that the markup tool uses to decide whether and how it should handle the mouse button down event. Currently the method looks like this:

```js
this.handleButtonDown = function(event, button) {
    if (this.allowNav || (this.is2d && (avp.isRightClick(event, this.viewer.navigation) || avp.isMiddleClick(event)))) {
        // If pan tool won't handle button down, then pass over the event
        if (this.panTool && this.panTool.handleButtonDown) {
            return this.panTool.handleButtonDown(event, button);
        } else return false;
    }
    return true; // Consume event
};
```

Where `avp` is just a shortcut to the `Autodesk.Viewing.Private` namespace.

```js
viewer.toolController.getTool('markups.core').handleButtonDown = function (event, button) {
    // Return true when you want the measure tool to "capture" the event and process it somehow,
    // or false when you want to ignore the event and allow other tools on the stack to handle it
};
```

Comment: I ended up modifying the `handleButtonDown` for the markup tool and it worked great! Thanks.